# How to create an interface/form in django where the user can use tools such as bold and italicize before submitting (similar to tools in google docs)

Tags: html, django

I am making a django website where a user inputs an essay. I want to the user to be able to use tools in order to "prettify" their essay by changing font, color, and other elements, and use tools such as bold and italics.

For example, if you see the interface where you can ask a question in stack overflow, you can see formatting information on the top.

[Stack Overflow Create Question Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy2kN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you can use django-ckeditor in your admin. select your field and customize it, for example code:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  form = ArticleModelForm
  content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorUploadingWidget())
  prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',), }
  class Meta:
    model = Article

admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
admin.site.register(ArticleComment)
```